# Trigger Action on jQuery Load Event Completion

Tags: jquery

I have a web page which loads select boxes dynamically using jQuery Load Event

```
jQuery('#opt_test').load('getextra.php?query=ls&id=2').change();
```

Another select box depends on the data of this one which is bound to the change event.

```
jQuery('#opt_test').change(function () {
    var test = jQuery('#opt_test').val();
    alert ('var');
    jQuery('#opt_host').load('getextra.php?query=ls&id=4&master=' + test );
})
```

I have two problems, I can't seem to raise the change event for #opt_test using the load event above.

If I manually duplicate a part of my code to bypass this issue, I find that the alert displaying the value of the select is before the load completed so it shows the old value.

How can I get this event to trigger after the load as completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to set a callback function that will be called on completion of the asynchronous call.  Otherwise, `.change` can (and probably does) execute before.  Change to:

```
jQuery("#opt_test").load('url', function () {
   $("#opt_test").change();
});
```

Comment: It didn't call my event with .change, however I was then able to cheat and duplicate my code which made it work.